# Use an ng-if if the content is editable. Angular.js

Tags: angularjs

https://plnkr.co/edit/7QscOzRc8mji7IwhccpZ?p=preview

I have an accordion. And I am using in each one the option of:

```
contenteditable=true
```

What I want to do, if the accordion has the property "contenteditable" assigned in true, then the ng-click executes the function:

```
ng-click="$event.stopPropagation();"
```

The previous line, inhibits that the accordion is open.

If contenteditable is false, then have the normal behavior. And the chord can be opened by clicking.
I do not know how to accommodate this, in sight, to adjust the ng-if to my need.

```
<uib-accordion close-others="true">
 <div ng-repeat="faq in faqs">
      <div uib-accordion-group class="panel-default" is-open="faq.open">
          <uib-accordion-heading >
              <span contenteditable="true" data-directive ng-model='faq.pregunta' href="#" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation();">{{faq.pregunta}}</span> <i class="pull-right glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-down': faq.open, 'glyphicon-chevron-right': !faq.open}"></i>
          </uib-accordion-heading>
          <span  contenteditable="true" data-directive ng-model="faq.respuesta" ondrop='return false;'>{{faq.respuesta}}</span>
      </div>
  </div>
 </uib-accordion>
```

thank you.

note:
In the version of bootstrap that I have in the project, when clicking on the title of the accordion, the page is reloaded. I solved this by removing the "href" attribute from it, directly in the bootstrap library. In the github I put the modified bootstrap.js link, I do not know how to publish it or consume it from this page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a click handler in the controller:

```
$scope.click = function($event) {
   if ($event.target.getAttribute('contenteditable') === 'true') {
      $event.stopPropagation();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could:

Add a editable property to your list:

```
$scope.faqs=[
        {"pregunta": "pregunta1", "respuesta": "respuesta1", "open": true, "editable": true },
        {"pregunta": "pregunta2", "respuesta": "respuesta2", "open": false, "editable": false},
        {"pregunta": "pregunta3", "respuesta": "respuesta3", "open": false, "editable": true}
    ];
```

And then check on ng-click, something like:

```
<button ng-click="faq.editable ? $event.stopPropagation() : whatever()"></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

you might be able to use a directive for this.

```
app.directive('contentEditable', function($parse) {
return {
restrict: 'A',
link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
    if(typeof attrs.contentEditable =="undefined" || attrs.iscontenteditable != "true")
        return;

    var fn = $parse(attrs.contentEditable);
    elem.bind("click",fn);
    }
}
}
);
```

Then, you could simply write the line like this:

```
<span  iscontenteditable="true" content-editable="$event.stopPropagation();" data-directive ng-model="faq.respuesta" ondr
```

try the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/brhardwick/n42cwvj9/2/